# Laravel append overall total value on pagination result

Tags: laravel, append

I have a Laravel query using pagination.

I want to be able to return the result based on the pagination but also get the overall total of the query and append this to the return. So for example the pagination is set to 5 but the overall total might be 20.

```
$query = Model::paginate(5); 
$queryTotal = $query->total();
$query->append($queryTotal);
return $query;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Laravel Paginator does this already.**

You can see that when [serializing results to JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#converting-results-to-json) there is a `total` key which represents all rows matching that query.

You can also see there is a `total` method available from the paginator:

```
$results->total()
```

Along side other methods that can be found in the [Pagination Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginator-instance-methods)

Answer (score 1):

The paginate function returns a `LengthAwarePaginator` object. It simply not possible to add another field to this object.

Your best option is to manually create a new collection in which you merge the `LengthAwarePaginator` with your newly added data.

An example would be:

```
$query = Model::paginate(5);

$addition = collect(['totalResult' => $query->total()]);

$queryData = $addition->merge($query);

return $queryData;
```

Naturally, if you just return the `LengthAwarePaginator` object, you can simply call the total() function, if you use it in your blade files for example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tested with Laravel 10 and works successfully

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = Model::paginate(5); 
return $query;
```

You can access overall total using

```
{{ $query->total() }}
```

For more Info read [Paginator instance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginator-instance-methods)

Comment: Perfect - thanks bhavinjr and Bogdan I should have checked the results.